# Why is my content rendering for a second then disappearing when trying to pass props? I am using react-redux

Tags: react-redux

I am trying to render content from one component to another. I have a search component with a text form, date form, and number form. When I submit the info, it renders on the results screen for a second and then disappears. I would like the content to stay rendered until a user searches again.

Thank you.

https://github.com/jasonbean3000/redux-passing-props

https://superlative-pithivier-b7794b.netlify.app

```
Results.jsx

import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { resultsSlice, addedSearchResults, addServerResults, addDateResults, addIdResults } from '../../app/resultsSlice';
import './Results.css'



export default function Results() {
    
    const searchResults = useSelector(addedSearchResults);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    
    
    
    return (
        <div className="results" >
         <h3> Server: {searchResults.server.server}</h3>   
         <h3> Date: {searchResults.server.date}</h3>  
         <h3> ID: {searchResults.server.id}</h3>  
        </div>
    )
};
```

break

```
Search.jsx

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addedSearchResults, addServerResults } from "../../app/resultsSlice";
import './Search.css'

export default function Search() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    

    const [serverSearch, setServerSearch] = useState({});

    const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
        const {name, value} = target;
        setServerSearch((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [name]: value
        }));
    };

    // const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    //     event.preventDefault();
    //     alert(JSON.stringify(serverSearch, '', 2));
    // };

    const handleSubmit = () => {
         dispatch(addServerResults(serverSearch));
    };

    return( 
        <div className="search">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
                <button>Search</button>
            </div>
            <label >
                <input
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={serverSearch.server}
                    id="server"
                    name="server"
                    type="string"
                    placeholder="Server Name"
                    >
                    </input>
            </label>
            <label >
                <input 
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={serverSearch.date}
                    id="date"
                    name="date"
                    type="date"
                >
                </input>
            </label> 
            <label >
                <input
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={serverSearch.id}
                    id="id"
                    name="id"
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="Server ID"
                >
                </input>
            </label>
        </form>  
        </div>
    )
    
};
```

break

```
resultsSlice.js

import { createSlice, createSelector } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    server: '',
    date: '',
    id: ''
}

const resultsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'searchResults',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        // selector function addServerResults, takes state as argument
        // returns what is needed by the component from the state
        addServerResults(state, action) {
            state.server = action.payload;
        },
        addDateResults(state, action) {
            state.date = action.payload;
        },
        addIdResults(state, action) {
            state.id = action.payload;
        }
    }
})


export const { 
    addServerResults,
    addDateResults,
    addIdResults 
    } = resultsSlice.actions;
export default resultsSlice.reducer;
export const addedSearchResults = (state) => state.results;
```

Answer (score 0):

got an answer from codecademy forums

I needed to add prevent default to Search component